# Tabular Model Deployment Failed

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, tabular, ssas-tabular, powerbi-datagateway

I have `Visual Studio 2019` and I have added "Analysis Services" as an extension. I created a `tabular` model and imported Excel files. When I go to deploy the model to a `tabular` server, the metadata is successful but the files contain the following error:

> 'Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB
>   or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] Could not find a part of the path
>   OLE DB or ODBC error: The command has been canceled..'

When I go into `ssas`, I am able to see the data model but is blank: no tables, nothing. Please help resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use UNC path
Here is solutions
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/1c3a860d-38a3-4c04-b79c-238a98fbb688/quotcould-not-find-a-part-of-pathquot-while-executing-package-through-stored-procedure?forum=sqlintegrationservices